# Making my own stop-words list from a certain community, is tf-idf good enough?

Tags: nlp

So I have some tweets from my country and I want to make a my own stop-words list. Is tf-idf good enough? Are there any statistical methods that would be better?

Answer (score 0):

Tf-idf scores are the normalized counts. It might be more useful to use the raw counts to identify potential stopwords.